# socket.io client 'emit' shows a weird error in chrome console

Tags: node.js, socket.io, emit

I am developing a simple application using the current latest versions of nodejs + socket.io on Windows. I have encountered a problem when the socket get created on the client side, but socket.emit results in the following output in the console (using Google Chrome):

```
GET http://0.0.34.184:8888/socket.io/1/?t=1321385855665&jsonp=0
```

Which is quite strange because I am testing on localhost:8888 so it should be at least 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.34.184. The socket.io client on the page is requested from the server in the  tag as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Then I connect using the following code:

```
socket = io.connect('localhost:8888');
socket.on("my_event", receiveNetEvent);

console.log('LOG: sio init complete, socket=' + socket);
```

The log states that socket=[Object object] which is not null or undefined so everything should work.

The sending itseld is performed in the following function:

```
function sendRequest(request){
    socket.emit('request', request);
}
```

The request object, passed to the function is formed and passed like this:

```
var initRequest = {};
initRequest.subject = 'weather';
initRequest.key = 'initial';

sendRequest(initRequest);
```

And it is a valid json object according, again, to `console.log()`.

All this leaves me totally clueless about any possible reason of the happening.

Comment: I cannot believe that. I have spent almost a day trying to catch the bug! And it turned out that i just did not put the 'http://' part in front of the 'localhost:8888' address!!! So the zeroes appearing there are from the messed-up bits I guess...

Comment: Still it puzzles me why socket.io is so ignorant on this, while it is so easy to forget the http thing that novadays is not usually enforced. It could at least throw a warning since a client socket cannot be open to anywhere else than http and it is clear that the header is missing from the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding http:// to the connect path. That solved this error for me.

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
```

Comment: Thanks. For anyone interested, switching window.location.href to window.location.origin added http:// to the URL I was connecting to (using Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue but I had a different reason. My setup was running the socket client on a tomcat server with port 9000 and was connecting to localhost:80 running nodejs, what i didn't realize is the port was mandatory even if it was 80 by default.

SO i gave the port and replaced

> io.connect('http://localhost') with io.connect('http://localhost:80')

Because both my servers were pointing to same domain which in this case localhost... socket io for some reason was taking port 9000

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem but resolved it by forcing only xhr-polling to server side javascript and that worked out.

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
    io.configure(function () {
      io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
    });
<..Rest code..>
```